# Why should I typedef enum when I use it as function return type or argument

Tags: c, enums

I want to use ***enum*** as function return type or as a argument. But when I give it as is, it's giving error message. But if I ***typedef*** the same, it's working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum        // if *typedef enum* is used instead, it's working fine
{
    _false,
    _true,
} bool;

bool func1(bool );

int main()
{
    printf("Return Value = %d\n\n", func1(_true));

    return 0;
}

bool func1(bool status)
{
    return status;
}
```

Please help me understand this. Thank you.

Comment: Just to mention `<stdbool.h>` that was introduced in C99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not making a new *type* `bool`, instead you are declaring a *variable* named `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

You've got the syntax wrong.

If you're not using `typedef` then it should be this:

```
enum bool
{
    _false,
    _true,
};
enum bool func1(enum bool );

enum bool func1(enum bool status)
{
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
enum
{
    _false,
    _true,
} bool;
```

declares a *variable* `bool` of an anonymous enum type.  `typedef enum { ... } bool;` defines a type called `bool` that can be used to refer to the enum type.

You can also write

```
enum bool
{
    _false,
    _true,
};
```

but then you have to refer to the type as `enum bool`.  The most portable solution is to write

```
typedef enum bool
{
    _false,
    _true,
} bool;
```

i.e. defining an enum type called `bool` and a general type called `bool` that refers to it.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax you have used is wrong. Use it as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum bool        // if *typedef enum* is used instead, it's working fine
{
    _false,
    _true,
} ;

enum bool func1(enum bool );

int main()
{
    printf("Return Value = %d\n\n", func1(_true));

    return 0;
}

enum bool func1(enum bool status)
{
    return status;
}
```

Instead if you use typedef you can directly use `bool` instead of `enum bool`.

Also to quote C99 standard:

```
Section 7.16 Boolean type and values < stdbool.h >

1 The header <stdbool.h> deﬁnes four macros.
2 The macro
bool expands to _Bool.
3 The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. They are
true : which expands to the integer constant 1,
false: which expands to the integer constant 0, and
__bool_true_false_are_defined which expands to the integer constant 1.
4 Notwithstanding the provisions of 7.1.3, a program may undeﬁne and perhaps then redeﬁne the macros bool, true, and false.
```

If you have a **compiler which compiles to C99** standard then you can just include `stdbool.h` and use bool like `bool b = true;`.